# Odd chapter heading appearing in middle of chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I get a very odd chapter heading in the middle of my abbreviation chapter in my thesis. I simply cannot figure out why and have tried with \clearpage and other tricks, but none worked.

[image: The "empty" chapter appearing in contents]

[image: Chapter heading in section]

My full main.tex file and abbreviation file can be seen here: 
[Main.tex file](http://pastebin.com/hdenKfXs)

[Abbrevations file](http://pastebin.com/6kFeudEh)

Minimal example. Main.tex file:
    \documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside, english]{report}
    \input{include/packagescommands}
    \input{include/settings}

```
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt} %spacing between paragraphs
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents
\input{include/abbreviations}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%% CHAPTER 1 INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage \setdefaulthdr \pagenumbering{arabic} \setcounter{page}{1}
\input{include/dummy}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Abbrevation.tex file:

```
\chapter*{Abbreviations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textit{Abbreviations}}

\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{0.8}

\begin{center}{
\begin{tabular}{l c l}
A, C, G, T, U&&adenine, cytosine, guanine, thymine, uracil\\
AFM&&atomic force microscopy\\
AGE&&agarose gel electrophoresis\\
...
\end{tabular}
\newpage
\begin{tabular}{l c l}
MASP(s)&&MBL-associated serine protease(s)\\
MBL&&mannan-binding lectin (also known as mannose-binding lectin)\\
...
\end{tabular}}
\end{center}
```

Dummy.tex file

```
\chapter[Dummy chapter]{\uppercase{Dummy chapter}}\label{ch:dummy}
 dummy text\cite{okholm_quantification_2014}
\section{dummy}
\subsection{dummy}
```

My packages and settings can be seen here [Packages](http://pastebin.com/518Mu0be)

[Settings file](http://pastebin.com/BkAAwfqv)

The relevant parts are extracted below, however, other parts could be relevant this is just my gut feeling.

Packagecommands.tex

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fncychap}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{sectsty}
```

Settings.tex

```
%titlespaceing
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{30pt} % this alters "before" spacing (the second length argument) to 0
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{10pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{10pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{10pt}{0pt}

% Fancyheader (see packagescommands.tex for default/special)
\pagestyle{fancy}

 \newcommand*\HUGE{\Huge}
 \newcommand*\chapnamefont{\normalfont\LARGE\MakeUppercase}
 \newcommand*\chapnumfont{\normalfont}
 \newcommand*\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries}

 \newlength\beforechapskip
 \newlength\midchapskip
 \setlength\midchapskip{\paperwidth}
 \addtolength\midchapskip{-\textwidth}
 \addtolength\midchapskip{-\oddsidemargin}
 \addtolength\midchapskip{-1in}
 \setlength\beforechapskip{18mm}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\filleft}
{{\chapnamefont\chaptertitlename}%
 \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{.8em}%
   \resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
   \hspace{.8em}%
   \rule{\midchapskip}{\beforechapskip}%
 }%
}%
{25pt}
{\chaptitlefont}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{40pt}{40pt}

% Title font
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}
```

Any help with be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please don't make your question dependent on external file hosters. Just make a small MWE that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Hi sam, thank you for your comment. The only issue is I really don't know where the issue stems from. I will try adding som extra line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Near the beginning of your document you execute the command `\setspecialhdr`, which is defined in `include/settings.tex` as follows:

```
    \newcommand{\setspecialhdr}{%
    \fancyhead[RE, LO]{\slshape \chapter}%
    \fancyhead[RO, LE]\thepage{}%
    \fancyfoot[C]{}%
}
```

The command `\chapter` in the second line is responsible that on every second page a new chapter is opened, as part of your fancy heading. What was your intention of putting `\chapter` there? By the way, it looks like the commands before this definition actually should go into the definition (at least when comparing it to the other header definitions in this file).

As a side note, your abbreviations file contains a `\bgroup`, but no closing `\egroup`.

Comment: Hi Gernot thank you, I wanted it to read "Chapter 2" in the header.

Comment: Thank you Gernot, it was the \chapter in the fancyhead which messed up the layout.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Next time you mess around with the definitions, check immediately the consequences. If you get unexpected results, it is reasonable to assume that the problem was introduced with the most recent changes.

Comment: To get the chapter number into the heading, replace the faulty `\chapter` by `\chaptername~\arabic{chapter}`.

Comment: Perfect thank you. Can you also clarify this:
- How do one make it read CHAPTER 2 instead of Chapter 2?
- How do one insert the chapter title without the CHAPTER 2?
- How do one make the above title in CAPS?

Thank you

Comment: @J.Doe It's best not to ask followup questions in the comments. Ask a new question about this - and provide a MWE - a short compilable document that illustrates the problem.

Comment: It seems you are reinventing the wheel. I suggest to start all over regarding the design of the document layout. Remove all packages manipulating the layout, like `fancyhdr`, `geometry` etc. Start with the document class `book`, `scrbook` or a similar one for books and structure your document with the commands `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`. See e.g. [this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20538/110998). The roman numerals, chapter title in the heading etc will already be ok.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce your issue. Please make sure your MWE exposes the problem. (And the MWE does not require any editing and is actually *minimal*! Just try downloading your MWE yourself and compile in a clean directory before asking, please.)

I would suggest that you also scan any aux, toc, lot, … files and see if there is any `\chapter` command. Then you can look for a command/package that writes to this auxiliary file.

(Addendum: as the problem has been found by gernot, the first thing to search for would of course be any `\chapter` commands in your tex files.)

Also, have a look at the `pdflatex` output.
It shows you which file generates the chapter:

```
(foo.tex (baz.tex)
chapter 1.
[2] [3] 
) (bar.tex [4] …)
```

Here, foo.tex generates chapter 1, and also writes pages 2 and 3. At the end of page 4, bar.tex was being typeset (but foo.tex might be responsible for the first part of page 4).

(I have not enough reputation to post this as a comment, so please bear with me.)

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your comment. Oddly I cannot find chapter 1 in the main console output.

My output looks like this:

Comment: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TS1/aer/m/n' undefined
     (Font)              using `TS1/cmr/m/n' instead
     (Font)              for symbol `textregistered' on input line 38.

   [2])
    Chapter 1.

    Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
    (hyperref)                removing `\unhcopy' on input line 61.

    Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
    (hyperref)                removing `\strutbox' on input line 61.

Comment: Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (25.79993pt): 
      Make it at least 199.83449pt.
      We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
      This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.

    [3] (./include/dummy.tex
    Chapter 2.

Comment: Can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/4DgtDDxB

And here in full:
http://pastebin.com/PFLZWt8d

Comment: The log file is not accessible. Is it intended that the page number "iv" is in the left margin in your screen shot? Also, the chapter is somehow overwritten over the text. Try to simply remove the `\newpage` and center environment. Try longtable instead.

Comment: Hi Martin, no def. no intended :) Can you access the log file now?