# Disable numbering of sub-sectioning commands under a starred sectioning command

Tags: sectioning

I wish to have a "Introduction" section that is not numbered, with subparts within it. I wish the subsections of that section not to be numbered, yet the whole thing to appear in the table of contents.

If I use

```
\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\subsection{First part of intro}
...
\subsection{Second part of intro}
```

...then the \subsection commands will (in the numbering scheme I use) generate numbering such as "0.1 First part of intro" both in-text and in the TOC.

The following generates what I want:

```
\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\subsection*{First part of intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{First part of intro}
...
\subsection*{Second part of intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Second part of intro}
```

Is there a way to automagically do this? My problem is that I have to type the `\addcontentsline` everywhere, when I would like to have something where `\section*` triggers a switch to "non-numbered mode" where each \subsection command is expanded to the pair of `\subsection*;\addcontentsline` commands or something similar (and the next `\section` switches back to "numbered mode").

EDIT: disabling numbering of subsections for the whole document is not desired.

Comment: FWIW Christian Hupfer had posted a comment that made me found http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20538/what-is-the-right-order-when-using-frontmatter-tableofcontents-mainmatter#20547 which (although inferior in my particular case) might be of use for future readers.

Comment: Note that `\frontmatter` usually turns of the numbers of `\chapter` only. With `book` the section numbers even still have the chapter prefix, e.g., `0.`. Other classes may behave different, e.g., `scrbook` omits the chapter number prefix for `section`, `subsection` etc. and `figure` and `table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `secnumdepth` for the introduction and afterward:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}% number only levels up to -1 (section is 1)
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{First part of intro}
\subsection{Second part of intro}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}% back to default of article.cls
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First part of first section}
\subsection{Second part of first section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's neat. I had no idea the TOC would be generated correctly if the secnumdepth was changed inside the document.